# Google AppMaker Registration form with Photo Upload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-app-maker

Hope you are all well.

Wondered if anyone out there can help. With Google Appmaker, is it possible to create a application form to send to applicants outside our organisation with file upload ability?

We want to get people to apply with the usual name, email etc. But then want them to be able to upload a photo of themselves.

All I can see is the Drive picker widget but wondered if there was a way of getting them to browse their computer and upload and submit.

Google Forms doesn't allow file uploads, otherwise it would have been perfect for us.

Thanks

Glen

Comment: Google forms allows file uploads

Comment: Indeed uploading files is supported, here are more details (https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/google-forms-file-upload-feature)

Comment: Thanks for the response :-) However it's not supported without Google sign in which if we are sending to various applicants externally it will be an issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sample app: [Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/drive-picker/) to let users upload files from their computers. Please note that [uploading files with Google Forms](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/google-forms-file-upload-feature) is supported.

Comment: Thank you :-)

Its supported, however you need a google sign in to do an upload and external applicants might not be on Google. 

Ill look into Drive picker

Comment: If it's working, please consider to accept the answer :) 
Also, if your use case implies allowing anonymous users, please check this thread https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87855/how-can-someone-answer-my-survey-form-or-google-form-without-creating-their-own